# Como mostrar dos valores máximos de una lista?

Tags: python

quiero saber como puedo hacer que me muestre en pantalla dos valores máximos de un conjunto de notas.

Por ejemplo:

Nota = [79,77,99]

Que en pantalla me imprima las notas mayores son 79 y 99 por ejemplo si se entiende. Hay que hacer un if??

Ademas quiero con esos dos valores obtenido, calcular el promedio o sea con 79+99/2? Los puedo guardar en unas variables?

Comment: `print(max(Nota))`

Comment: No; no es necesario hacer un if. Basta con hacer `print(sorted(Nota)[-2:])`. Asi de simple.

Comment: @CandidMoe esa era mi segunda opción

Answer (score 1):

La forma sencilla de hacerlo es ordenando la lista y obteniendo sus 2 últimos elementos, luego usamos la función `sum` para sumar la lista y luego dividimos

```
Nota = [79,77,99]
maximos = sorted(Nota)[-2:]
prom = sum(maximos)/2
print(prom)
```